PMD - Bad hyperlink URL in report
Hi everyone I hope you are doing well.
I'm currently using "PMD" to scan and find bugs/problems in my Salesforce apex code.
The following command is working fine
pmd check -d “C:\...\default\classes” -f summaryhtml -R “category\apex\security.xml” -r “outputHTML.html” 
An HTML file is generated correctly, but when I try to open "the solution" by clicking the hyperlink this one is not working. It tries to open a local file, not the Documentation. It says an error like this:
Your file couldn’t be accessedIt may have been moved, edited, or deleted.
ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND

I am using the latest version pmd-dist-7.1.0-bin
Thank you, regards.

I can't reproduce this. For me, the link target URL is "https://docs.pmd-code.org/pmd-doc-7.1.0/pmd_rules_apex_security.html#apexsharingviolations" - what is the URL exactly, that you get in the report?

You might be using static ruleset file and when the output file is generating it pickup the resources from your local system, If you want to generate hyperlink from PMD server create ruleset with updated PMD server link resources.
